# как узнать какое событие происходит в данный момент когда ГУГЛ переводчик виджет переводит сайт на другой язык

Tags: javascript

Куда нужно посмотреть чтобы увидеть какое событие происходит в момент перевода страницы?

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: Когда использую плагин selectbox и меняю вид страницы то данный переводчик перестает работать

Comment: Приведите код демонстрирующий проблему